# Is there a way to sort a vector in segments?

Tags: c++

If I have a vector with an odd number of elements and want to sort the vector in segments, how could I construct a loop that does this but doesn't access anything out of bounds?

Like an array like this: 
`[4, 5, 6, 3, 10, 2, 0]` (size: 7)

And I want to sort in segments of 2, so it becomes like this: 
`[4, 5, 3, 6, 2, 10, 0]`

I was thinking something like this, but then the vector would access arr[8] which is out of bounds.

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.size(); i = i + 2) {
  sort(arr.begin() + i, arr.begin() + i - 1);
}
```

Comment: Your approach is correct. Just make sure that you get your iterators to remain valid. Remember that if you have 7 elements in the vector, `begin() + 7` is a valid iterator for comparison purposes but not for dereferencing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options spring to mind:

First, you can constrain your loop:

```
const int SegmentLen = 2;
for (int i=0; i+SegmentLen-1 < arr.size(); i += SegmentLen)
    std::sort(arr.begin()+i, arr.begin()+i+SegmentLen);
```

Second, you can loop a fixed number of times:

```
auto segments = arr.size() / SegmentLen;
for (int i=0; i < segments; ++i)
    std::sort(arr.begin() + (i*SegmentLen), arr.begin() + (i*SegmentLen) + SegmentLen);
//Handle any leftovers
```

Comment: Are you sure about the `-1`?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Fairly certain, yes. Testing with different segment sizes appears to work.

Comment: Okay, yep, it checks out. Just making sure ^_^ (I do worry though that this is a little bug-prone perhaps as it's not necessarily completely intuitive)

Answer (score 0):

Just get the first even number less than or equal to the size of the array and then use that as the stop condition for the loop.

```
int main(){
    std::array<int, 7> arr = {4, 5, 6, 3, 10, 2, 0};
    auto size = arr.size() % 2 ? arr.size() - 1 : arr.size(); // if odd subtract one else use size
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size - 2; i += 2)
        std::sort(arr.begin() + i, arr.begin() + i + 2);
    for (auto e : arr)
        std::cout << e << " ";
}
```

Outputs:

```
4 5 3 6 10 2 0
```